# Kotlin Apollo GraphQL - How to modify normalized cached item with ApolloStore API?

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo GraphQL for my Kotlin Android Application.
My Normalized Cache has for example this item:

```
 "Post:247" : {
    "__typename" : Post
    "id" : 247
    "name" : testname
    "favorites" : 4                                                                                                   }
```

How can I edit this item in cache using ApolloStore API and increment the favorites count by 1 so that all my watchers get notified?

The official ApolloStore Docs are not helpful at all.